# Find the minimum perimeter of the triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, maxima-minima

Consider point $A(5, 2)$ and variable points $B(a, a)$ and $C(b,0),\, a\in R, \, b\in R$. If the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ is minimum, find $a$ and $b$.

---

#### My attempt:

$\begin{align}
P&=AB+BC+CA\\
&=\sqrt{(a-5)^2+(a-2)^2}+\sqrt{(a-b)^2+(a)^2}+\sqrt{(5-b)^2+(2)^2}
\end{align}$

I tried to partial differentiate the equation w.r.t. $a$ and $b$ and solve for $a$ and $b$ and obviously I didn't get the answer as the derivative of square root into its argument is getting much more complicated. I didn't show the calculations here as it is very tedious.

I also know that this is not the expected method to solve this problem. It has something to do with *"For minimum length, path followed by light ray is to be traced"*. But I don't know how to apply it here.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the other answers, I must confess that my score in geometry is very close to $Z^{--}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we draw $\triangle ABC$.  Reflect $A$ about the line $y = x$, to the point $A' = (2,5)$.  Also, reflect $A$ about the line $y = 0$ to the point $A'' = (5,-2)$.  Then the side $AB$, when reflected about $y = x$, becomes $A'B$, and the side $AC$, when reflected about $y = 0$, becomes $A''C$, and the path $A'BCA''$ has the same length as the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ because $A'B = AB$ and $A''C = AC$.  For what choice of $B$ and $C$ do we have the shortest possible distance between $A'$ and $A''$, and therefore the least possible perimeter?

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

*Using derivatives.*

If you compute
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial a}=\frac{2 (a-b)+2 a}{2 \sqrt{a^2+(a-b)^2}}+\frac{2 (a-5)+2 (a-2)}{2\sqrt{(a-5)^2+(a-2)^2}}=0$$ you can solve for $b$ (just a quadratic equation i $(a-b)$. This gives
$$b_1=\frac{3 a}{5-a} \qquad \text{and} \qquad b_2=\frac{3 a}{a-2}$$
Now, use
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial b}=\frac{b-5}{\sqrt{(b-5)^2+4}}-\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a^2+(a-b)^2}}=0$$

Replace $b$ by $b_1$ and plot $\frac{\partial P}{\partial b}$ as a function of $a$ and discard any solution corresponding to $a=2$ or $a=5$. Do the same with $b_2$. You just have one solution which is very close to $a=3$ for $b_1 \sim \frac 92$ which makes, as an *approximation*,
$$P_{min}\sim \frac{1}{2} \left(5 \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{17}\right)\approx 7.65172$$

Now, we can polish the solution for $a$ using Newton method. It would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & 3.00000 \\
 1 & 2.90898 \\
 2 & 2.90008 \\
 3 & 2.90000
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, $a=\frac {29}{10}$, $b=\frac {29}{7}$ give
$$P_{min}=\sqrt{58} \approx 7.61577$$

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are going for, but here is a solution without calculus.

Let $l_1$ and $l_2$ be the lines $y = x$ and $y = 0$, respectively. The problem is to choose $B$ and $C$ on lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ so as to minimize $AB + BC + CA$.

Let $A_1 = (2,5)$ be the reflection of $A$ with respect to $l_1$ and let $A_2 = (5,-2)$ be the reflection of $A$ with respect to $l_2$. Then since $B \in l_1$, we have $A_1 B = AB$. Similarly, $CA_2 = CA$.

Thus the problem now becomes to select $B$ and $C$ so as to minimize the length of the broken line $A_1 B C A_2$. This length is minimal when the broken line is in fact a segment. Therefore $B$ and $C$ must be chosen as the intersections of segment $A_1 A_2$ with lines $l_1$ and $l_2$.

Answer: $B = (29/10,29/10), C = (29/7,0)$.